# .Net SQL Server Management Objects Table / View / Procedure Collections

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

How can I skip over the system views/tables/procedures when I am attempting to grab a list of these objects for a project?

Right now I am doing a string comparison on the names and/or schemas, but I assume that there is a much better way to do this.

**Code**:

```
''' <summary>
''' Grab all our tables, attempting to skip over system tables
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub GrabTables()
    Dim _Db As Database = Srv.Databases(0)
    Dim _Tbls As ParallelQuery = _Db.Tables.AsParallel()
    For Each tbl In _Tbls
        If Not tbl.Name.Contains("sys") Then
            _Tables.Add(New TableTyping() With {
                        .Name = tbl.Name,
                        .Schema = tbl.Schema,
                        .Columns = ProcessColumns(tbl.Columns)})
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(_Tables.Count)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Grab all our views, make sure to skip over system, and information views
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub GrabViews()
    Dim _Db As Database = Srv.Databases(0)
    Dim _Tbls As ParallelQuery = _Db.Views.AsParallel()
    For Each tbl In _Tbls
        If Not tbl.Name.Contains("sys") AndAlso Not tbl.Schema.Contains("sys") AndAlso Not tbl.Schema.Contains("INFORMATION") Then
            _Views.Add(New TableTyping() With {
                        .Name = tbl.Name,
                        .Schema = tbl.Schema,
                        .Columns = ProcessColumns(tbl.Columns)})
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(_Views.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a long week.  There is a property of each object called `IsSystemObject` that does the trick.  I wasn't seeing it in the intellisence due to using the `AsParallel`

Comment: Also, most system objects are in the `sys.` schema.  Except those annoying diagramming objects, which I typically filter out with a pattern on the name (`NOT LIKE 'dt_%').